# Playing music from an iFrame/Background and a HTML5 sound effect simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, wkwebview

I'm looking to provide these 2 simple functionalities below for an interactive experience for iOS users:

1. Play audio from an iFrame video continuously and occasionally play short HTML 5 snippets of sounds
2. Play audio from iOS's native background player (ex. when users play music from the Spotify or Apple Music app) and occasionally play short HTML 5 snippets of sound

Is this possible in WKWebView? I'm using Ionic to build an app and have to rely on this and can't use SafariViewController.

Comment: It should normally, but I don't know much about IOS. Have you tried? Try it and edit this post if there is an error or a problem you encounter

Comment: I'm trying it today. Will update this thread

Comment: Sounds good! Let us know if it worked, so it will help others asking this question as well.